# Errors when getting elevation data using R

Tags: r, elevatr

I am trying to get elevation data for Russia. Below are my codes. I used geoboundaries to get the boundary of Russia first. Then use get_elev_raster to get the elevation data.

```
library(rgeoboundaries)
library(elevatr)

russia <- rgeoboundaries::geoboundaries(country = "Russia",adm_lvl = "adm0")
get_elev_raster(russia,z=4)
```

However, it returns an error message:

```
Error in proj_expand(locations, prj, expand) : 
  The elevatr package requires longitude in a range from -180 to 180.
```

What's wrong with my codes? I tried similar codes for some European countries like France and Italy. The codes all worked well.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the region you are trying to get crosses the international date line, which `elevatr` doesn't like. You will need to get the East and West parts separately

```r
library(rgeoboundaries)
library(elevatr)
library(sf)

russia <- rgeoboundaries::geoboundaries(country = "Russia",adm_lvl = "adm0")

rus <- as.data.frame(st_coordinates(russia))


r_west <- get_elev_raster(rus[rus$X > 0 & rus$X < 180,], z = 4,
                prj = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

r_east <- get_elev_raster(rus[rus$X < 0 & rus$X > -180,], z = 4,
                          prj = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
```

Now you have two rasters for the East and West parts of Russia. We can plot this as follows:

```r
df <- setNames(as.data.frame(r_west, xy = TRUE), c("x", "y", "elevation"))
df2 <- setNames(as.data.frame(r_east, xy = TRUE), c("x", "y", "elevation"))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = elevation)) +
  geom_raster() +
  geom_raster(data = df2) +
  geom_sf(data = russia, fill = NA, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

[image]